# How to insert emoji into MYSQL 5.5 and higher using Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, utf-8, utf8mb4

I am trying to insert emoji's  into a certain filed in my mysql table.
I ran alter command and changed the collation to **"utf8mb4_general_ci"**

```
  ALTER TABLE XYZ MODIFY description VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Table details after above query:

```
+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Column      | Type         | Character Set | Collation          |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+
| description | varchar(250) | utf8mb4       | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

After this I ran the query to update **description** column with emoji's, every time I ran below query, the emoji is replaced by '?'.

```
  update XYZ set description='a test with : ' where id = 1;
```

But when i print the result from a select query for the same id, it displays' '?' in place of emoji. The result was:

```
  "a test with : ??"
```

Carried out necessary changes into model file.
**Please accept my Apologies for not making it clear, would appreciate any lead in this matter.**

Comment: Have you tried adding ’OPTIONS’: {’charset’: ’utf8mb4’} in django database configuration along with username and password ?

Comment: Yes, i did that too.

Comment: Did you try to change /etc/mysql/my.cnf options?

Comment: Not really, what should i change in there?

Comment: Tried changing **my.cnf** file also, but its of no use.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'charset': 'utf8mb4',
                    'use_unicode': True, },
    },
}
```

`my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
default-collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

Answer (score 0):

this save me on MYSQL 8.0.1

**my.cnf**

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Were you using Django?  (I hope you have updated past 8.0.1 -- that is a pre-release; one should move on to at least the "GA" version.)