# How to use two tables with same name in two different schema in mysql with django

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-orm

I am using two mysql schemas X and Y, both contains multiple tables but there is one table that has same name in both the schemas.

Both the schemas are as follows:

```
+--------------+--+--------------+
| X            |  | Y            |
+--------------+--+--------------+
| name         |  | album_info   |
+--------------+--+--------------+
| invite       |  | photo_info   |
+--------------+--+--------------+
|   photo      |  |   photo      |
+--------------+--+--------------+
| user_details |  | temp         |
+--------------+--+--------------+
```

Now, I want to query on both the tables but when I write the table structure in models.py file with same name it throws error/exception.
I declared both table in routers.py file as below:

```
  modelDatabaseMap = {
    .
    'photo': 'default',
    .
    .
    .
    'photo': 'y',
}
```

(X is my default schema).
Declared i models.py as below:

```
 class Photo(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
     has_tagged_with = models.IntegerField()
     has_reposted_with = models.IntegerField()
     .
     .

     class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'photo'

 class Photo(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
     account_id = models.IntegerField()
     p_id = models.IntegerField()
     is_profile = models.IntegerField()
     .
     .

     class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'photo'
```

Now, the ambiguity is first in name, in declaration in models.py and secondly in querying.
I am stuck at how to query on both the tables separately through orm. **Any help/lead about this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Do you have a connection for each schema? How is your `DATABASES` configuration?

Comment: DATABASES configuration is as follows:
       `DATABASES = {
             'default': {
                    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql',
                    'NAME': 'X',
                    'USER': DATABASE_USERNAME,
                    'PASSWORD': DATABASE_PASSWORD,
                    'HOST': DATABASE_HOST_NAME,
                    'PORT': '3306',
                    'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
              }      
       }`
Same way I added schema Y into the dictionary.

Comment: that's the point. You have two database configurations? one `default` and other `y`, for example?

Comment: I don't have two db configurations, default and Y both schemas are mentioned inside DATABASES = { }
I have only one DATABASES config

Comment: DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql', 'NAME': 'X', 'USER': , 'PASSWORD': , 'HOST': , 'PORT': '3306', 'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}, }, 'y': { 'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql', 'NAME': 'Y', 'USER': , 'PASSWORD': , 'HOST': , 'PORT': '3306', 'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}, } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your `DATABASES` configuration, you can try:

1. Change your Models name or create a new app with a different `models` module for each schema:

   ```
   class YPhoto(models.Model):
       ...

   class XPhoto(models.Model):
       ...
   ```
2. Create a `router.py` module:

   ```
   class MyRouter(object):

   def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
       if model.__name__ == 'YPhoto':
           return 'Y'
       return None

   def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
       if model.__name__ == 'YPhoto':
           return 'Y'
       return None

   def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
       # Maybe you want to prevent relations between different schemas, it's up to you
       return True

   def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
       return True
   ```
3. Add the router to the `settings.py`:

   ```
   DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp.models.MyRouter',]
   ```

Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/) about database routing.

Comment: Oops, I've noticed that you must check for all tables within `Y` schema in the `if`s. Maybe you are better creating a new app for the tables in the `Y` schema

Comment: Thanks, will try this.

Comment: I would request to answer another question of mine, link is below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496101/how-to-insert-emoji-into-mysql-5-5-and-higher-using-django-orm?noredirect=1#comment75996316_44496101